# android :button not working after i go to the activity again

Tags: android

i have a button in an activity to send a message by it

the problem is if the person entered the page the button send the message

but if he exit from the page and opened it again .. the button not working

its like became disabled

and the solutions that i used

1 - i disabled the butterknife library and used

```
 setOnClickListener
```

2 - i added

```
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

but it didnt work

and i used the log as a test
.. and its like the button became disabled

although

another page have a similar code

and the button working perfectly in it

and this is the activity xml code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:textDirection="rtl"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context=".Activities.SentMessagesActivity">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tb_sent_Messages"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/et_sent_messages"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tb_sent_Messages"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:id="@+id/srl_sent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_0"
        android:background="@drawable/new_background"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:id="@+id/rv_sent_messages"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"  />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ib_sent_messages_send"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_40"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_40"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/et_sent_messages"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_sent_messages"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextborders"
        android:hint="@string/write_ypur_message"
        android:maxHeight="@dimen/dp_70"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:onClick="openKeyboard"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ib_sent_messages_send"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>
```

and the Java code

```
public class SentMessagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button mSend;
    @BindView(R.id.tb_sent_Messages)
    Toolbar mToolbar;
    @BindView(R.id.rv_sent_messages)
    RecyclerView mMessagesList;
    @BindView(R.id.et_sent_messages)
    EditText mMessage;
    @BindView(R.id.srl_sent)
    SwipeRefreshLayout mRefresh;


    TinyDB db;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessagesHolder> mAdapter;
    private ActionBar mActionBar;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mFriendContacts;
    private DatabaseReference mMyMessagesRef;
    private DatabaseReference mFriendMessagesRef;
    private DatabaseReference mFriendRef;
    private DatabaseReference mMyRef;
    private DatabaseReference mReference;

    private int count;
    private int mCurrentPage = 1;

    private String myImage;
    private Dialog mProgressDialoge;
    private String myId;
    private String friendId = "";
    private String Image = "";
    private Long State;
    private String Name = "";
    private TextView mToolTitle ,mToolState;
    private TimeAgo timeAgo;
    private String myName = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sent_messages);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mProgressDialoge = new Dialog(SentMessagesActivity.this);
        friendId = getIntent().getStringExtra(App_Constants.FRIEND_ID);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        myId = mAuth.getUid();
        db  = new TinyDB(this);

        mSend = findViewById(R.id.ib_sent_messages_send);
        mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(App_Constants.USERS_CELL).child(myId).child(App_Constants.USER_INFO_CELL);
        mReference.keepSynced(true);
        mMyMessagesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(App_Constants.USERS_CELL).child(myId).child(App_Constants.MESSAGES_CELL).child(App_Constants.SENT_CELL).child(friendId);
        mMyMessagesRef.keepSynced(true);
        mFriendMessagesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(App_Constants.USERS_CELL).child(friendId).child(App_Constants.MESSAGES_CELL).child(App_Constants.RECEIVED).child(myId);
        mFriendMessagesRef.keepSynced(true);
        mFriendRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(App_Constants.USERS_CELL).child(friendId).child(App_Constants.USER_INFO_CELL);
        mFriendRef.keepSynced(true);
        mMyRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(App_Constants.USERS_CELL).child(myId).child(App_Constants.CONTACTS_CELL).child(App_Constants.SENT_CELL);
        mMyRef.keepSynced(true);
        mFriendContacts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(App_Constants.USERS_CELL).child(friendId).child(App_Constants.CONTACTS_CELL).child(App_Constants.RECEIVED);
        mFriendContacts.keepSynced(true);
        App_Utilities.initializingProgress(mProgressDialoge);
        mProgressDialoge.show();

        mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 myImage= dataSnapshot.child(App_Constants.USER_IMAGE_CELL).getValue().toString();
                 myName = dataSnapshot.child(App_Constants.USER_NAME_CELL).getValue().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        mMyMessagesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                count = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        initializingActionBar();
        intitializingRecyclerView();

        mRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mCurrentPage++;
                intitializingRecyclerView();
            }
        });
        refreshingLayout();

        mSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String Text = mMessage.getText().toString().trim();
                Toast.makeText(SentMessagesActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Text))
                {
                    message(Text.trim());
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null)
        {
            App_Utilities.startEndActivity(SentMessagesActivity.this,StartActivity.class);
            mProgressDialoge.dismiss();

        }
        mAdapter.startListening();

        mProgressDialoge.show();
        new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (count > 15)
                {
                    mMessagesList.scrollToPosition(App_Constants.TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD - 1);
                } else
                {
                    mMessagesList.scrollToPosition(count - 1);

                }
                mProgressDialoge.hide();

            }
        }.start();


        mFriendMessagesRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if ((boolean)dataSnapshot.child(App_Constants.SEEN).getValue() == false)
                {
                    mFriendMessagesRef.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child(App_Constants.SEEN).setValue(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        db.putBoolean(App_Constants.ISWORKING,false);

    }

//    public void onClickImage(View view) {
//
//
//    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        db.putBoolean(App_Constants.ISWORKING,true);

    }




    private void refreshingLayout()
    {
        mMyMessagesRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if (count > 15)
                {
                    mMessagesList.scrollToPosition(App_Constants.TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD - 1);
                } else
                {
                    mMessagesList.scrollToPosition(count - 1);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    private void message(String Text) {
        final HashMap map = new HashMap();
        map.put(App_Constants.MESSAGES_CELL,Text);
        map.put(App_Constants.FROM,myId);
        map.put(App_Constants.SEEN,false);
        map.put(App_Constants.TYPE,App_Constants.SENT_CELL);
        mMyMessagesRef.push().setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    map.put(App_Constants.TYPE,App_Constants.RECEIVED);
                    mFriendMessagesRef.push().setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                mMessage.setText("");
                                if (count > 15)
                                {
                                    mMessagesList.scrollToPosition((App_Constants.TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD * mCurrentPage )- 1);
                                } else
                                {
                                    mMessagesList.scrollToPosition(count - 1);
                                }

                            }
                             else
                            {

                                Toast.makeText(SentMessagesActivity.this, R.string.failed_to_send, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SentMessagesActivity.this, R.string.failed_to_send, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initializingActionBar()
    {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.messages_toolbar,null);

        mActionBar.setCustomView(view);
        mToolTitle = findViewById(R.id.tv_toolbar_name);
        mToolState = findViewById(R.id.tv_toolbar_state);

        mFriendRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Name = dataSnapshot.child(App_Constants.USER_NAME_CELL).getValue().toString();
                Image = dataSnapshot.child(App_Constants.USER_IMAGE_CELL).getValue().toString();
                State = (Long) dataSnapshot.child(App_Constants.ONLINE_CELL).getValue();

                mToolTitle.setText(Name);
                mToolTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        openProfile();
                    }
                });
                if (State == App_Constants.ZERO)
                {
                    mToolState.setText(R.string.online);
                } else
                {
                    mToolState.setText(TimeAgo.getTimeAgo(State,getApplicationContext()));
                }
                mProgressDialoge.hide();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void intitializingRecyclerView()
    {
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mMessagesList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mMessagesList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        Query mQuery = mMyMessagesRef.limitToLast(mCurrentPage * App_Constants.TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions mOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Message>()
                .setQuery(mQuery,Message.class).build();

         mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessagesHolder>(mOptions) {
             @Override
             protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessagesHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Message model) {

                 if (model.getFrom().equals(myId))
                 {
                     holder.fillSentMessage(myImage,model.getMessages(),myName);
                 } else if (model.getFrom().equals(friendId))
                 {
                     holder.fillReceivedMessage(Image,model.getMessages(),Name);
                 }
             }

             @NonNull
             @Override
             public MessagesHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                 View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_sent_message,parent,false);
                 return new MessagesHolder(view,parent.getContext());

             }
         };
        mMessagesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.startListening();
        mRefresh.setRefreshing(false);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.block_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.bt_menu_block:
                blockUser();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void blockUser() {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(SentMessagesActivity.this)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.block_this_person))
                .setMessage(R.string.would_u_like_to_block)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        yesBlock();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    private void yesBlock() {
        mMyRef.child(friendId).child(App_Constants.TYPE).setValue(App_Constants.BLOCKED_FROMME).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    mFriendContacts.child(myId).child(App_Constants.TYPE).setValue(App_Constants.BLOCKED).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                mMyMessagesRef.removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                                        {
                                            mFriendMessagesRef.removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                                    App_Utilities.startEndActivity(SentMessagesActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void openProfile()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SentMessagesActivity.this,UserActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(App_Constants.FRIEND_ID,friendId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openKeyboard(View view)
    {
        ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .showSoftInput(mMessage, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    }
}
```

this is happening on some mobiles like samsung 
but working fine in others

Answer (score 0):

Add your

```
Button mSend;
    @BindView(R.id.tb_sent_Messages)
    Toolbar mToolbar;
    @BindView(R.id.rv_sent_messages)
    RecyclerView mMessagesList;
    @BindView(R.id.et_sent_messages)
    EditText mMessage;
    @BindView(R.id.srl_sent)
    SwipeRefreshLayout mRefresh;
```

Put the logic above or initialize the widgets and button without butterknife, in the `onCreate()` function